# ColdFusion structs with two dimensions

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, coldfusion, struct

Please help me understand why this code doesn't work. I'm getting the "attempting to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.Double as a structure with members.

```
<cfoutput>

<cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
    <cfset moveStruct[i] = i>
    <cfset moveStruct[i]['X_TWO'] = i * 2>
</cfloop>

<cfset length = structCount(moveStruct)>

<cfloop from="1" to="#length#" index="i">
    #moveStruct[i]# - #moveStruct[i]['X_TWO']#<br />
</cfloop>

</cfoutput>
```

I was expecting to get:

1 - 2
2 - 4
3 - 6

etc.

I'm trying to learn how to build structs with two dimensions in ColdFusion so that I can save rows of user input and submit a different query for each row. I'm using this to try to figure out how I am building my struct wrong.

Sometimes in CF I like to pass a query to a struct using code like this (below), so that as I loop through it I can compare certain fields to the previous row to determine whether to insert a header or footer for that group of data, especially in ordered queries/reports. I'm trying to achieve something similar in my actual project. The fact that this code works is what I'm using as a basis to try to do this other project by hand:

```
<cfloop query="prevQuery">
    <cfloop list="#prevQuery.columnList#" index="col">
        <cfset prevStruct[currentRow]['#col#'] = evaluate(#col#)>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Small aside, if you are using `evaluate()` to grab query column values - it is not necessary. Just use associative array notation `queryName["columnName"][rowNumber]`. ie Something like `prevQuery[col][prevQuery.currentRow]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
<cfset moveStruct = {}>
<cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
  <cfset moveStruct[i]['ONE'] = i>
  <cfset moveStruct[i]['X_TWO'] = i * 2>
</cfloop>

<cfset length = structCount(moveStruct)>

<cfloop from="1" to="#length#" index="i">
  #moveStruct[i]['ONE']# - #moveStruct[i]['X_TWO']#<br />
</cfloop>
```

Comment: That worked! I appreciate the quick solution, this will let me move forward in my project. So if I understand right, if I'm building a two-dimensional struct, I can't set the first dimension independent of  the second dimension? IE, any time I set a value in the struct, I've got to be setting a value in [here][and here]?

Comment: yes, basic data structure.  Maybe you should be looking into using 2d array instead.  Use `ArrayNew(2)`.

Comment: Cfresh - The issue you have is movestruct[i] = i;
This sets movestruct[1] = 1, so you can't have ['X_TWO'] as a struct inside the number 1... thats the issue. Henrys solution doesn't set movestruct[1] to anything, it sets the child. Basically, you were wiping out your own structure. Hope that clarifies.